# MVC EF4 SP roolback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

my app type is MVC Application. and DB is SQL SERVER 2008.  Every operation on DataBase tables are going with Stored Procedures. in one page i  am going to add new rows to two different tables with two different stored procedures. between this tables has relation. in my [Post]Create() Action i call both of this SP. but my problem is: if any of this stored procedures executed with no success then roolback. No any rows must inserted no to first table no to the second table. How i can do this process?

To my ViewModel includes both of this tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

```
using (var scope = new new TransactionScope())
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    contex.SP1();
    contex.SP2();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: good article. never heard about this class. i think it is that i was searched for. Hi to Russia